# SVG attributes beaten by CSS&style in priority?

Tags: css, html, svg

I have SVG line with specified stroke attribute.

`<line class="myLine" stroke="red" x1="40" x2="200" y1="100" y2="100" stroke-width="5" />`

And there is a CSS class that has stroke value in it:

```
line.myLine
{
  stroke:green
}
```

How come CSS class actually takes priority over explicit svg attribute and the line renders as green???

At the same time if I add style attribute with stroke in it, then style overrides css class & stroke svg attribute.
So the priorities order is the following:

1. style attribute
2. css class
3. svg attribute

How come SVG attribute is the lowest priority???

https://jsfiddle.net/pmunin/6j5woyry/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A long read from the standard: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#UsingPresentationAttributes

> The presentation attributes thus will participate in the CSS2 cascade as if they were replaced by corresponding CSS style rules placed at the start of the author style sheet with a specificity of zero. In general, this means that the presentation attributes have lower priority than other CSS style rules specified in author style sheets or ‘style’ attributes.

Answer (score 7):

Hopefully this isn't too late, but this helped me actually understand the issue:

Attributes on SVG elements are at the lowest level of priority, as mentioned in the attribute spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#PresentationAttributes

This means if you want a particular attribute on a specific element, add it to the `style="[...]"` attribute for the element such that it has the highest specificity and therefore the highest priority.

For example, if you want to override stroke as in the original example, use `style="stroke: red;"` instead of `stroke="red"`.  If you're using a library such as D3, make sure you're using `.style()` instead of `.attr()` to set high-priority styles.

Hope that helps others.